# Why does the Open Dialog show up twice?

Tags: javascript, electron, semantic-ui

Here's the code:

```
$('#browseButton').click(() => {
document.getElementById('directory').value = dialog.showOpenDialog({
    filters: [
        {name: 'somefile.exe', extensions: ['exe']},
        {name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*']}
    ],
    properties: ['openFile']
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="ui form">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="directory">SteamCMD Directory</label>
            <div class="ui action input">
                <input id="directory" type="text">
                <button id="browseButton" class="ui secondary button">
                    <i class="icon folder open"></i>
                    Browse
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Using Semantic UI

When I clicked OK in the Open Dialog, a new Dialog opens. I had to select the file twice to get the `document.getElementById('directory').value` to register.

Comment: You should include the full code snippet, with the html you are working with.

Comment: What is `#browseButton` and `directory`? What library is providing the `dialog` object? If `#browseButton` is a `<input type="file">` then your event-handler is not cancelling the default event, that might be the reason why.

Comment: Is this button also bound to a click or __doPostback (or any other event)?

Comment: @Dai I'm using electron

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve this issue :

```
     document.getElementById('browseButton').onclick = () =>
      {
        var file =document.getElementById('directory').value
       dialog.showOpenDialog((file) => {
       filters: [
       {name: 'somefile.exe', extensions: ['exe']},
       {name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*']}
                ],
             properties: ['openFile']
    });
   });
```